# How to configure and retrieve the value from a g:select in Grails?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, gsp

I have a g:select in my view that displays a list of products:

```
<g:form name="addproductform" action="saveProductToInventory" method="post">
    <g:select from="${products}" name="product" value="${it?.id}" />
    <g:hiddenField name="inventory.id" value="${inventoryInstance.id}" />
    <input class="save" type="submit" value="Save product" />
</g:form>
```

${products} is a list of all products. If I print the params variable that is passed to the controller, I get this:

> [product:Test Product,
>   inventory:[id:1], inventory.id:1,
>   action:saveProductToInventory,
>   controller:inventory]

The **product** key contains the name, and not the ID which I thought it would contain when I added value="${it?.id}" to the g:select tag.

How do I need to declare the g:select tag to render the product's name as it is right now, but pass the product's id as value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the optionKey argument to the tag.

e.g.

```
<g:select from="${products}" name="product" value="${it?.id}" optionKey="id" />
```

The value arg is used to select the current value of the field.

Comment: Tried it, and it works. Thanks! But before that I tried with optionKey="${it?.id}" and it gave me the same results as before. I'm not sure I understand how the g:select knows to get the id from each product, instead of trying to get the id from the list itself.

Comment: g:select is calling it.<optionKey> for you on each row to generate the value of the select option.